# How does dhcpd stop on centos?

Tags: isc-dhcpd

Normally we use service dhcpd stop to stop dhcpd, but cmd `service` is just a script, thus it should be something executed by script so that dhcpd finally stops. For example as I write a script, when I type `service dhclient stop`, it executes `dhclient -r` inside of script.

So could anyone please tell me what does `service dhcpd stop` actually do to stop dhcpd service?

Comment: What version of CentOS are you asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about CentOS 6.x or older, then `service dhcpd stop` runs `sh /etc/init.d/dhcpd stop`, which ends up running `kill <PID of dhcpd>`.

If CentOS 7.x, then `service dhcpd stop` runs `systemctl stop dhcpd`, which will tell `systemd` to do the actual stopping.

If `dhcpd.service` is a native systemd service file, then `systemd` will do the killing, probably by just making a `kill(<PID of dhcpd>, SIGTERM)` system call unless a specific `ExecStop=` command is specified in the service file or it does not successfully stop all the processes belonging to the control group created by `systemd` for the service. See `man systemd.kill` for more details and options for variations.

If it's an auto-generated wrapper for a legacy SysVinit start/stop script, then systemd will run `sh /etc/init.d/dhcpd stop`, much like older CentOS versions did.

---

You commented that you're using CentOS 7.3 - so `systemd` is involved.

If you configure `dhcpd` to serve multiple network interfaces with a single instance of `dhcpd`, then shutting down `dhcpd` will obviously end DHCP service on all interfaces at the same time.

If you want to start multiple instances of `dhcpd` (one for each interface), then you can just kill the `dhcpd` process associated with the interface whose DHCP service you wish to stop.

To make management easier, you could write your own custom `.service` files for `dhcpd` and place them into `/etc/systemd/system` to start/stop each of the multiple instances of `dhcpd`. Then you could use ''service dhcpd-ge1 start'' etc. according to how you choose to name the `.service` files. See `/lib/systemd/system/dhcpd.service` on your system for an example, and adjust the command line arguments in the `ExecStart=` line to suit your needs for each instance.

Comment: Thank you so much!! But I'm still not clear with some points. Since sometime I don't use `service dhcpd start` but `dhcpd ge1` ( allows me to specify an individual interface with dhcpd), does your answer means that, there's no way to stop dhcpd on individual interface(like dhcpd stop ge0 ) ? coz if there is not a dhcp stop button, once we use `service dhcpd stop`, all dhcpd on each interface will stop, and I'm wondering that is there a way that I can stop a spicified interface running dhcpd?

Comment: Updated my answer.